# Lisp: Measuring performance of functions

Tags: performance, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, factorial

So far, while testing the speeds of different approaches to writing the same function, I've been using the `time` function, and generally it gives me a good indication of the relative speeds of different functions (since they typically differ by around 100k cycles).

While attempting to find the fastest approach for a `factorial` function, however, `time` has been lacking. Not only do these methods seem to differ by only 10k-30k cycles, but their overall time vary by around half that amount too (which is expected, I guess).

The three `factorial` functions:

```
(defun factorial-recusion (n)   ; 1st      
  (if (equal n 1) 
      1
      (* n (factorial (- n 1)))))

(defun factorial-loop (n)   ; 2nd
  (let ((solution 1))
    (loop for x from n downto 2
       do (setf solution (* solution x))
       finally (return solution))))

(defun factorial-do (n)     ; 3rd
  (let ((solution 1))
    (do ((x n (1- x)))
    ((< x 2) (return solution))
      (setf solution (* solution x)))))
```

So, I guess I have two questions:

1.) Which method of `factorial` should be fastest (if any actually is), and why?

2.) If I were to find out for myself the faster function through a general method, what's the best way to do so (for some reason I think LOC is a bad indicator of speed)? Perhaps there is a way to view the disassembly of Lisp bytecode? Or maybe there's a better, more rigorous way?

I'm currently running Linux 3.2.0-26, SBCL, on Ubuntu 12.04 x86-64.

Comment: What implementation of CL are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SBCL does not compile to 'bytecode'. It compiles to native machine code.

You can disassemble a Lisp function by using `DISASSEMBLE`.

Speed in your factorial function is dominated by bignum arithmetic multiplication once the numbers get into the bignum range.

To make it clearer: which iteration construct you use, DO or LOOP, does not matter much. Most of the time is spent multiplying bignums. The recursive version also does not make much of a difference.

That's a typical benchmark problem: many simple numeric benchmarks are dominated by runtimes of a few arithmetic operations (like multiplication of bignums). They will not measure much of the different in speed of general language operations (like the various types of control flow).

A slow Lisp with a fast bignum library will likely be faster than an optimizing Lisp compiler with Bignum code written in Lisp.

Comment: oh oops, I left it in there. At first I wrote (and (...) (return solution) but I then realised how stupid that was. Disassemble seems to be what I need. So I gather that's also the best way to measure performance? Do you think there's a straight answer to my first question? thanks!